# Placement of IF RIGHT logic in excel formula

Tags: excel-formula

In the below image, I use the following formula to get the New York scores of students (the specific version pulls Laura's NY score of 36:

`=INDEX(A:B,MIN(IF((ROW(A:A)>MATCH("New York",A:A,0))*(LEFT(A:A, 5)="Laura"),ROW(A:A),"")),2)`

However, the one amendment I want to make is to say if the name cell ends in (Base), the score that is pulled should be 100 minus the value in column B (i.e. it would show 64).  Where do I put the logic IF and RIGHT logic within the formula?

Appreciate any help.

[image]

Comment: You are going to have to double-up your formula; one to retrieve 36 and once to check if it should be subtracted from 100. Better cut down on those full column references.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
=ABS(INDEX(B:B, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW(INDEX(A:A, MATCH("new york", A:A, 0)):INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99, B:B)))/(LEFT(INDEX(A:A, MATCH("new york", A:A, 0)):INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99, B:B)), LEN("laura"))="laura"), 1))-(RIGHT(INDEX(A:A, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW(INDEX(A:A, MATCH("new york", A:A, 0)):INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99, B:B)))/(LEFT(INDEX(A:A, MATCH("new york", A:A, 0)):INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99, B:B)), LEN("laura"))="laura"), 1)), LEN("(base)")) = "(base)")*100)
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks!  

However, if I try to apply the same formula to data in an external sheet, I get a #REF! error.  I appreciate this is a different question, but does anyone know why applying a working formula to the same data in an external file would do this?  (The data is exactly the same, it was originally copied and pasted from this source file)